# Netbeans and repository

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-7

i'm developing a C++ project in Netbeans. My project now it is stored in a repository, but in these days I'm working in different PC stations.
One has an old 32 bit architecture and one works at 64 bit.

The makefile for the stations are different! How can I realize a NetBeans project that it is independent from the PC architecture? If i want to use my project in a third station, I don't want to worry about problems the computer architecture.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a repository for C/C++ my tipp is: dont check in makefiles. They depend on your machine and they are generated *automaticly*! So no need for them.

In general you can exlude following parts from **`nbproject`** directory:

- complete directory  `private`
- all makefiles / bashes (= everything ending with `.bash` or `.mk`)

--> only check in `configurations.xml` and `project.xml` from `nbproject`.